# https settings for ionic app server settings

Tags: ssl, ionic-framework, https, mean

The application is build in MEAN stack and we are able to run the port successfully in 3001 port and our web application is running perfectly in HTTPS ... Now we have build the ionic app for the same application where we are using the same back up..

The ionic app is not logging in or form is not getting submitted..

Do we need to use a seperate port for the same application to use for ionic like

ionic in 8001
and web application (Angular) in 3001

What is the procedure to run the ionic app in SSL (https)

Any suggestion will be great helpful and thank you in advance

Comment: what error is showing in chrome console  when run `ionic serve`?

Comment: No errors are displayed.. We are just not able to login after downloading from the Google play store

Comment: i think you are looking for this, pls go through it http://ivancevich.me/articles/ignoring-invalid-ssl-certificates-on-cordova-android-ios/

Comment: Actually it's a perfect valid SSL working fine for website but when coming to app.. I have a question.. Do we need another port for ionic or can run in same angular port where web is running.. What settings need to be added in server.js file for making ionic app work with ssl

Comment: No there is no need for two ports! i think you misunderstood with angular development port (which is 4200) and application server port. Angular uses its port for only development purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.. In api do we need to add any code to add the key.store of ionic.

Comment: Dude i dont have much knowledge in networking, but with my knowledge, In server api you dont need to do any changes i think, you have to work out on the mobile app side. Cordova is a wrapper for mobile application which gives the ability to run your js in cordova web view (which is browser). you need to find out `how to pin the ssl certificates with cordova?` or other wise use the above link i have resolved with. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

My code is as follows which worked perfectly:

```html
var express = require('express');
var DataController = require('./user/DataController');
var UserController = require('./user/UserController');
var db = require('./database/database-db'); 
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
// res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
// res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8100");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
});

app.use('/user', UserController);
app.use('/data', DataController);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send("Welcome to the secure mobile and web development world");
});

// This settings are for HTTPS, SSL web applications.

// var https = require("https");
// var fs = require("fs");

// var options = {
//   key: fs.readFileSync("/home/path/ssl/keys/key.key"),
//   cert: fs.readFileSync("/home/path/ssl/certs/crt.crt")
  
//   };

// https.createServer(options,app).listen(3001);
// console.log('Welcome to the security world')


// This settings are only for HTTP sites

// var http = require("http");
// var fs = require("fs");

// http.createServer(app).listen(3001);
// console.log('Welcome to the security')



//This settings are for both HTTPS,HTTP SSL web applications.

var https = require("https");
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("/home/path/ssl/keys/key.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("/home/path/ssl/keys/crt.crt")
  };

https.createServer(options,app).listen(3001);
console.log('Welcome to the security world')
http.createServer(app).listen(3002);
console.log('Welcome to the proxy world')
```